# jpct-ae, deform shape

Tags: android, shapes, jpct

I used the code form jpct wiki to display the shape. Is there a way to deform this shape when screen is touched, without using blender or simiar apps? How to do it?

http://www.jpct.net/wiki/index.php/Hello_World

Comment: Ask your question in jPCT forum and you will get a good answer. The forum administrator (actually the creator of jPCT) is a very nice guy and usually reply within a day.